# Extend or inherit existing entries in .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following entry in my .ssh/config file:

```
Host myhost
    Hostname localhost
    User me
    ServerAliveInterval 30
    ProxyCommand ssh -q external-relay /usr/bin/nc -w 90 localhost 9889
```

Very simple, it allows me to access `myhost` from outside its NATed network, by bouncing off `external-relay`.

Most of the times I only want to SSH to `myhost`, without creating any SSH tunnels, but some other times I want to create various tunnels, for different purposes.

Nowadays I simply manually append the `-L` tunnel entries when I ssh to `myhost` but it's becoming increasingly difficult to remember which sets of ports  I need for which purpose.

I could just add those custom port forwarding commands as aliases, but what I'd really like is to have separate named entries in my `.ssh/config` file that basically create the connection to `myhost` and add the required tunnels, but I don't want to duplicate the whole `myhost` config everytime, because if/when I change the `external-relay`, I don't want to have to remember to change it in every entry that used it.

Is there a way to create an entry that *inherits* fom the `myhost` entry, and simply appends the required `LocalForward` directives for that particular tunnel case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Host myhost-*
    Hostname localhost
    User me
    ServerAliveInterval 30
    ProxyCommand ssh -q external-relay /usr/bin/nc -w 90 localhost 9889
```

followed by:

```
Host myhost-1
    LocalForward ...

Host myhost-2
    RemoteForward ...
:
```

`myhots-1` and `myhost-2` will derive settings from `myhost-*` (but CANNOT override them).

You definitely should have a look at the beginning of DESCRIPTION section (to see how options are applied to connection) and PATTERNS section of ssh_config man page.